# Sharing speakers between Windows notebook and Ubuntu PC, over wifi

Tags: audio, streaming

I'm having an Ubuntu running PC with audio system (speakers, volume regulator) connected directly to it's sound card. I'm looking for a solution to share the audio from windows-running notebook to this audio system. I'd also like to be able to temporary mute the audio stream from windows, or choose the audio source on the linux machine.
I'm not talking about sharing media, just the audio stream from windows! I don't want to sync music or so, just connect the notebook to the speakers over wifi, using linux PC as kind of a mediator.

Answer (score 1):

I looked around for a while, and did not find much. There is very little out there that can redirect Windows sound output besides the virtual sound cards used by remote desktop syle products.

I did find one possible solution. I found a program called [Jamcast](http://www.sdstechnologies.com/) which is primarily intended as a way to stream music from any possible windows source. It has special support for some programs, but also offers a virtual sound card feature that works by streaming all the audio, music or otherwise.

I've not actually tried this software, but it sounds like it should work. It does cost $30, which is not ideal, but at least it offers a 14 day trial.

On Linux you would just connect to the stream at `http://laptop_hostname:58642/Media/wav/CaptureStream` with some streaming media player.

The tricky part would be automatically connecting to the Windows laptop when it is powered on or resumes from sleep. You could have the Linux box poll every 5 minutes or so, but that may be more delay than you want. Another possibility: you could script something up where when the Windows machine starts/resumes it connects to some server on the Linux box, which launches MPlayer (or vlc, or other streaming app) with the right parameters.

Comment: thank you! this sounds like a way to go. I'll keep the question open a little bit in hope somebody finds less 'tricky' solution (yeah, vritual sound card is a bit tricky) ;)